# Can I add the R2 in the plots for pairs.panels from the pysch package?

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel, correlation, psych

I am trying to add the R2 into the plots somehow (I have a 5x5 correlation matrix).

What I have so far:

```
pairs.panels(corrdatEU[, c("Fe","Zn","Se","S","P")], 
                                      breaks=10,
                                      hist.col = 11, 
                                      main="Correlations between elements",
                                      stars=TRUE, ci=TRUE)
```

[image]